# Как работоть с ответом нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy, keras

На вход нейронной сети я подал текст который она должна классифицировать по 3  категориям. Получил следующий ответ:

```
[[0.4575766  0.45049337 0.45947695]
 [0.43210754 0.41918626 0.43070686]
 [0.43210754 0.41918626 0.43070686]
 ...
 [0.4575766  0.45049337 0.45947695]
 [0.4575766  0.45049337 0.45947695]
 [0.4575766  0.45049337 0.45947695]]
```

Список массивов равный по длине количеству слов в тексте.

**Вопрос:**

Как дальше работать с этими данными?

**Полный код скрипта:** https://pastebin.com/ufJZE4Jr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

model.predict() возвращает матрицу вероятности принадлежности к классам. Т.е. в каждой строке выходной матрицы вы получаете вероятности принадлежности данного элемента к каждому из трёх классов.

Чтобы выбрать класс с максимальной вероятностью можно воспользоваться функцией [np.argmax(matrix, axis=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

---

Пример:

```
In [1]: predictions = np.array(
   ...: [[0.4575766,  0.45049337, 0.45947695],
   ...:  [0.43210754, 0.41918626, 0.43070686],
   ...:  [0.43210754, 0.41918626, 0.43070686],
   ...:  [0.4575766,  0.45049337, 0.45947695],
   ...:  [0.4575766,  0.45049337, 0.45947695],
   ...:  [0.4575766,  0.45049337, 0.45947695]])

In [2]: predictions
Out[2]:
array([[0.4575766 , 0.45049337, 0.45947695],
       [0.43210754, 0.41918626, 0.43070686],
       [0.43210754, 0.41918626, 0.43070686],
       [0.4575766 , 0.45049337, 0.45947695],
       [0.4575766 , 0.45049337, 0.45947695],
       [0.4575766 , 0.45049337, 0.45947695]])

In [3]: np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
Out[3]: array([2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример?

Comment: @СергейАндреев, пример использования np.argmax() ?

Comment: да, для массива указанного в моём вопросе